# What is the recommended practice for loading packages in testthat tests?

Tags: r, testthat

In a commit called "[Don't attach dplyr backends](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/892cf876ec8044f1ec6f5ca7904f939fd9281262)", Hadley Wickham removed direct function calls from loaded packages. Probably to ensure that packages are not loaded directly, he changed function calls to a form of `packagename::function()`.

I didn't find an indication about this in his [book chapter on testing packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html).

For functins that I use rarely, I'm going to call them in this form `packagename::function()`. But I'm wondering about packages that I tend to use heavily such as the chaining operator from the dplyr (magrittr) package. Should these packages

1. be loaded in `tests/test-that.R`,
2. or in each test file under `tests/testthat/test-file.r`,
3. or should they be imported through my package's required Imports, as specified in the `DESCRIPTION` file?

Comment: Hadley [doesn't load them](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/tree/master/tests/testthat) in each .R file. He put `testthat` under the [Suggest](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) in DESCRIPTION. He does load it in [`testthat.R`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/tests/testthat.R). Feel free to follow this workflow.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Perhaps the OP means packages used for testing other than testthat, should they also be added to suggest in DESCRIPTION? I was looking for an answer to this when I can across this question.

Comment: Yes, I meant packages other than testthat.

Comment: this blog was helpful to me https://blog.r-hub.io/2020/11/18/testthat-utility-belt/